# Run db query IF querystring not null c# razor

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

I'm new to C# Razor and I want to run a very simple process - essentially I want to run a news page. If the page link contains an ID, I want the page to query the db against that value, e.g:

> ```
> var newsID = Request.QueryString["ID"];     
> var datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM News WHERE ID=@0", newsID);
> ```

And if there is no value, I want it to select the top record in the table, like so:

> ```
> var datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Top 1 ID, Title, Date, Text
> FROM news ORDER BY ID desc");
> ```

I'm trying to execute the check like this:

> ```
> if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null) {
> var newsID = Request.QueryString["ID"];    
> var datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM News WHERE ID=@0", newsID);        
> }else{<br />
> var datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Top 1 ID, Title, Date, Text, FROM news ORDER BY ID desc");}
> ```

However, as soon as I try to execute the queries from within the IF statement, the compiler fails telling me that datanewsitem.variable is not defined when I try to call it.

This is likely a fundamental flaw in my understanding of how C# works, but could anyone offer me a solution (with an example) for what I'm trying to do? It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

This has an easy fix.

You're defining the `datanewsitem` variable twice, once each within your `if` and `else` clauses.  This means it only is defined within the clause it belongs to (referred to as the variable's "scope".)

Change to:

```
myNewsType datanewsitem = null;
if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null) {
   newsID = Request.QueryString["ID"];    
   datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM News WHERE ID=@0", newsID);        
}else{<br />
   datanewsitem = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Top 1 ID, Title, Date, Text, FROM news ORDER BY ID desc");}
```

... where `myNewsType` is whatever the type name is of the `datanewsitem`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Ann - I've added datanewsitem as a string and moved newsID out of the IF statement (which got it compiling past the IF statetemnt) but I still get the following error:

>    'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It sounds as if at some point you have a string variable and are attempting to access its `Text` property.  However, as it says, `string` doesn't have a `Text` property or method.  The code you've posted doesn't show you accessing `.Text` of anything, but that's where I'd look:  any place where you're accessing `.Text`.

Comment: The item is datanewsitem.Text, which is accessed in the query.

Comment: Hmm. It sounds as if `datanewsitem` is a string, then, but your query should be returning a record object, based on what you've posted.  Well, if `datanewsitem` is a string, it should have a value.  What is the value?  Is it something you recognize?

Comment: Sorry, finding this comments section a bit fiddly. Code should read:

`var dataID = (int) db.QueryValue("SELECT Top 1 ID FROM news ORDER BY ID desc"); 
var newsID = Request.QueryString["ID"]; 

if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null) { newsID = Request.QueryString["ID"]; 
}else{ 
newsID = dataID; 
} `

Comment: I've had another thought about how to do this, and I've nearly got it working. Instead of calling the Query in the IF statement, we can identify the variable as above. We either use the Querystring ID number or take the ID from the last record in the table (dataID). It's just being a pain with the variable format at the moment, if I type in a number instead of dataID it works fine.

Comment: Is the problem because `dataID` will be a string and `newsID` an int?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Is there a way to force the dataID into an int? I may actually abandon trying to do this on a single page and just direct the basic news link to a page called "latestnews" and query the specific stories on a page called "news". It's sloppy and bad practice, but to be honest the amount of messing about with C# to perform a basic query that PHP or ASP can handle without issue is just starting to irritate. I do greatly appreciate your help though, just having someone take an interest is a huge help.

Comment: You can always try the `Convert.ToInt32()` function.  Guaranteed to turn a string into an int, assuming it's an unformatted representation of an int. It's a shame you're having so much trouble, I've found it less work than classic ASP (I don't know about PHP). This Q&A+comment format makes troubleshooting hard, though.